# Conditional input in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g, rdbms

I am using Oracle sql developer. I need to create a table:

```
EXTPROG (ActId, ActName)

ActId Varchar2(4), 
ActName Varchar2(10)
```

are the two columns. `ActId` should always start with `A`

How to do this while creating table?

Comment: Add a check constraint,  e.g. `ActId like 'A%'`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the functionality of `ActId` field.

- If you want to perform post-insert validation (e.g., you import data from somewhere) — jarlh's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289545/conditional-input-in-oracle-sql#comment58289039_35289545) fits perfectly. I would also take a look at `DEFERRABLE` option for constraints, it may be helpful in this case.
- If `ActId` is a surrogate primary key (or should be generated somehow) and you want to fill it yourself, I would recommend you to create a sequence for these purposes:

  ```
   insert 
     into EXTPROG (ActId, ActName)
   values ('A' || lpad(to_char(EXTPROG_SEQ.NextVal), 3, '0'), 'SomeName')
  ```

  In this case take into account relatively small size of your `ActId` field.